# Autocomplete text in textbox

Tags: c#

Every time I type in a character in the textbox there should be a suggestion/s in the textbox on the names that start with the letter that the user inputted. I will provide the image of the error that occur when I try to run the program[image]

```cs
private void View_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon);
    string sqlquery = "select firstname from [dbo].[tbl_registerStudent]";
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection autotext = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        autotext.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autotext;
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-Complete in textbox using data from a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236497/auto-complete-in-textbox-using-data-from-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: You should not close connection inside `while (sdr.read())` cycle - move it outside of loop

Comment: this is so wrong

Comment: Hi @tbhaxor I will try to read this question to see if it will answer my question. Thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: Hi @Quercus thank you for the small tip. Appreciate it alot!

Comment: Do not `Close` manually, but wrap into `using`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `con.Close()` from `while` loop.

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    autotext.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
}
con.Close();
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autotext;
```

Comment: Thank you @user2250152 this solved my answer!

Comment: Oh yes thank you for that. I'm new that's why I don't know to mark it that someone has answered my question. Thank you once again

Comment: I think only the very first line needs to be inside the loop, the rest can be put outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not `Close` *manually* but wrap `IDisposable` into `using`. Either

```
private void View_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  AutoCompleteStringCollection autotext = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

  string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon)) {
    con.Open();
 
    string sqlquery = 
      @"select firstname 
          from [dbo].[tbl_registerStudent]";
    
    using(SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con)) {
      using (SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (sdr.Read())
          autotext.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
      }  
    }
  }

  textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
  textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
  textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autotext;
}
```

Or starting from **c# 8.0** you can get rid of pesky `{...}`:

```
private void View_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
 
  using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon);
  
  con.Open();
 
  string sqlquery = 
    @"select firstname 
        from [dbo].[tbl_registerStudent]";
    
  using SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
  using SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();

  AutoCompleteStringCollection autotext = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

  while (sdr.Read())
    autotext.Add(sdr.GetString(0));

  textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
  textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
  textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autotext;
}
```